# PHP IBM SQL DB2 statement only updating only partially with no error messages

Tags: php, sql, db2, ibm-midrange

Code:

```
    $sql =      'UPDATE library/tablename ' .
           'SET foo1 = \'THIS IS A TEST\', foo2 = 1234567890, foo3 = 1234'.
           'WHERE foo4 = 165436';

    $stmt = db2_prepare($dbConn, $sql)
        or die("Error: Unable to prepare statement");

    $exec = db2_execute($stmt);
```

I run this in PHP and after it executes I go to look at the table and I see that the foo1 field has changed, but foo2 and foo3 remain their default values, which is zero.

If I run the $sql statement from "strsql" on the IBM terminal it runs and all fields are updated to the values I have specified. Does anyone have any idea as to what is going on here? This has had me stumped for hours.

Comment: -0.49 for embedding values into your SQL *while using the freaking prepared statement API*.

Comment: I had been using place holders and binding them but that wasn't working either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running the execute, you probably want to check the value of [SQLSTATE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.doc/doc/rdb2stt.html).  That will show you the actual error that DB2 is throwing at you.

You can retrieve the SQLSTATE in PHP using [`db2_stmt_error()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.db2-stmt-error.php), which will give you the SQL state of the last execution (if you pass a particular resource, the last execution on that resource).

If you'd like to output a human-readable SQL Error Message, you can use [`db2_stmt_errormsg()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.db2-stmt-errormsg.php), which will output the SQLSTATE and the corresponding error message string.

Comment: I tried this after the statement execute                   error_log(db2_stmt_error(). ' - '. db2_stmt_errormsg()); and I just got this in the log ' - '

Comment: Wow, ok so it was nothing wrong with the PHP or SQL. There was a new RPG program that was messing up the field values after I set them. Thank you for taking the time to help me out anyways.